# What is the explanation of this code?

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to learn Prolog. I have a problem and the solution for that in Prolog. Though I am unable to understand the code completely.

**The problem is -**

```
Write a procedure   mydelete( X, HasXs, OneLessXs ) that returns

%      ?- mydelete( 2, [1,2,3,4], L ) .    --> L = [1,3,4]

%      ?- mydelete( 2, [1,2,3,2], L ) .    --> L = [1,3,2] ; L = [1,2,3]
```

**Basically, the problem is t remove the member one by one which matches X and print the result after each removal.**

I have a solution , but, I am exactly, not sure how this code is working.

```
mydelete(X,[X|T],T).
mydelete(X,[H|T1],[H|T2]) :- mydelete(X,T1,T2).
```

As per my understanding, the first line, displays the L = ... when it finds a match with X in the head of the list.

In the second line of the code, it simply pops out the head from the input list and send that updated list recursively.

But, here, we haven't defined T2.

**Let us consider an example for that.**

```
mydelete( 2, [1,2,3,4], L ) .  --> this is the call.
```

**X=2, list is = [1,2,3,4], so, H=1, T=[2,3,4].**

So, it does not execute line 1 of the code. Now, it comes to the second line of the code.

```
mydelete(X,[H|T1],[H|T2]) :- mydelete(X,T1,T2).
```

**Here also X=2, H =1, T1=[2,3,4], T2= .**

So, on the next recursion,

**X=2, list = [2,3,4], H matches X, thus line 1 will get executed.**

**Therefore, X=2, T=[3,4]**

So, **it should print = [3,4].**(I know, [1,3,4] is the right answer. I am not able to understand the explanation behind this code)

**My, question is, what is wrong in my understanding?**

**And, what is the use of [H|T2] in**

```
mydelete(X,[H|T1],[H|T2]) :- mydelete(X,T1,T2).
```

Thanks! Please help me out!

edit: I tried removing H from [H|T2]. It is printing [3,4]. How H is adding 1 as the prefix to the list [3,4] ?

Comment: Given the problem description, I would not use `write` at all, but just have `L` unify to the correct answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I copied the code here a little wrong. I am changing it. Sorry for the trouble. I was trying something on my own. and I pasted it here by mistake. Sorry again! :(

Comment: `mydelete/3` is commonly called `select/3`, cf. https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to think of this as an imperative programmer is that the last argument is kind of the return value. You see that the first call you make "returns" `[H|T2]`, not merely `T2` this is how the first element of the list remains: after recursing to compute the value of `T2`, mydelete is adding `H` (which happens to equal 1 in this case) to the start of the returned list.

Comment: I think I am able to understand what you are trying to say. Let me please explain it once and please also let me know if I am wrong. the line 2 which is mydelete(X,[H|T1],[H|T2]) :- mydelete(X,T1,T2). initiates recursion and drops the head of the list each time. So, when the line 1 returns [3,4], the line 2 adds the prefix(H) to it when the control comes to the previous step. Have I understood correctly?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the use of `[H|T2]`?

In your explanations, you forgot to consider that the third argument, `L`, is being unified with `[H|T2]`. Up to this point, `L` was free (in your case), and now you know that it is a list starting with `H`. The rest of the list `T2` is now the third argument to the recursive call and will be unified likewise, until you reach the base case.

By the way, what happens when your list is empty?